# Any ideas on how to solve this? $\lim_{x\to \infty}x(\frac{1}{e}-(\frac{x}{x+1})^x)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Tried L'Hospital's rule, using logarithms and variable substitution. Guess I'm missing something or making mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: It's best that you show your work and give some meaningful context to your question. Just writing that you tried some approach and that didn't work does not constitute a meaningful context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that, for $x\to \infty$,
$$
\begin{split}
\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^x
& = \exp\left[ -x \log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]
\\ &= \exp\left[-x\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2} + o(1/x^2)\right)\right]
\\ & = \frac{1}{e}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2x} + o(1/x)\right)
\\ & = \frac{1}{e} + \frac{1}{2e x} + o(1/x).
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Yeah, taking -1 from logarithm is what I did miss. Thank you sir!